# Run a for loop to create dataframes by part of column name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to construct a dataframe with a for loop by part of a column name. I've tried this with as follows.

```
N = 10000
J = [2012,2013,2014]
K = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
L = ['h', 'd', 'a'] 
S = ['AR1','PO1','RU1']

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Y':np.random.uniform(1,10,N),
     'X':np.random.uniform(1,10,N),
     'Z':np.random.uniform(1,10,N),
     'J':np.random.choice(J,N),
     'S':np.random.choice(S,N),
     'R':np.random.choice(L,N)
    })

for a in ["X", "Y", "Z"]:
    for num in list(range(0, 10)):
        df['bins_{}'.format(a)] = df.groupby('S')["{}".format(a)].apply(pd.qcut, q=10, labels=np.arange(10))

        df['bin_{}_{}'.format(a, num)] = np.where((df['bins_{}'.format(a)] == num) & (df['R'] == 'a'),
                                                  (df['{}'.format(a)] * 2) - 2,
                                                  np.where((df['bins_{}'.format(a)] == num) & (df['R'] != 'a'), -2, 0))

df_Z0 = (df.bin_Z_0).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)
df_Z1 = (df.bin_Z_1).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)
df_Z2 = (df.bin_Z_2).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)

# for a in [str.startswith('bin_Z')]:
#     df_Z = (df.a).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)

df_Z0
```

Output is now with only the values in bin_Z_0;
[image]

However I want them from 0 through 9 and then subsequently for other columns (X, Y, etc.). Something like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by second level `S`:

```
print (df_Z0.sort_index(level='S'))
```

EDIT:

Solution replace `0` by `NaN` and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) - replace `NaN` by non NaN data:

```
df_Z0 = (df.bin_Z_0).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack()
                    .replace({0:np.nan})
df_Z1 = (df.bin_Z_1).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack()
                    .replace({0:np.nan})
df_Z2 = (df.bin_Z_2).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack()
                    .replace({0:np.nan})

print (df_Z0.combine_first(df_Z1).combine_first(df_Z2).fillna(0).sort_index(level='S'))
```

```
                   sum                         size          
J                 2012        2013        2014 2012 2013 2014
bins_Z S                                                     
0      AR1 -130.627936 -109.113076 -129.183069  114  102  115
1      AR1  -53.332480  -21.304159  -67.457064  111  102  118
2      AR1  -50.862985   34.782290   74.742122  106  111  113
3      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   96  107  128
4      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  109  103  118
5      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  109  109  113
6      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  113   88  129
7      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  108  106  117
8      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  121  107  102
9      AR1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  112  105  114
0      PO1 -102.842426 -104.375470 -143.081966  109  113  112
1      PO1  -24.968751  -28.222851  -57.769469  119  107  107
2      PO1    9.301271  -64.096715  -46.586959  108  116  109
3      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  120   88  125
4      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  108  110  115
5      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  100  110  123
6      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  132  109   92
7      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  120  108  105
8      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  109  114  110
9      PO1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  107  111  116
0      RU1 -110.563320 -124.948033 -121.455465  116  117  104
1      RU1  -17.513545  -48.205310  -32.040780  112  120  104
2      RU1   34.402681    3.013596  -23.436698  106  115  115
3      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  134   94  108
4      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   99  115  122
5      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  134  113   89
6      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   91  128  117
7      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  105  115  116
8      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  113  121  102
9      RU1    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  101  125  111
```

Another solution is possible if need replace data with `0` to non `0` data from another dataframe and no non `0` data are overlap in columns `sum`:

```
df_Z0 = (df.bin_Z_0).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size'])
                    .set_index('size', append=True)
df_Z1 = (df.bin_Z_1).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size'])
                    .set_index('size', append=True)
df_Z2 = (df.bin_Z_2).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size'])
                    .set_index('size', append=True)

print (df_Z0.add(df_Z1).add(df_Z2).reset_index(level=3).unstack().sort_index(level='S'))
```

```
           size                   sum                        
J          2012 2013 2014        2012        2013        2014
bins_Z S                                                     
0      AR1  114  102  115 -130.627936 -109.113076 -129.183069
1      AR1  111  102  118  -53.332480  -21.304159  -67.457064
2      AR1  106  111  113  -50.862985   34.782290   74.742122
3      AR1   96  107  128    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
4      AR1  109  103  118    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
5      AR1  109  109  113    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
6      AR1  113   88  129    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
7      AR1  108  106  117    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
8      AR1  121  107  102    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
9      AR1  112  105  114    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0      PO1  109  113  112 -102.842426 -104.375470 -143.081966
1      PO1  119  107  107  -24.968751  -28.222851  -57.769469
2      PO1  108  116  109    9.301271  -64.096715  -46.586959
3      PO1  120   88  125    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
4      PO1  108  110  115    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
5      PO1  100  110  123    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
6      PO1  132  109   92    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
7      PO1  120  108  105    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
8      PO1  109  114  110    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
9      PO1  107  111  116    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0      RU1  116  117  104 -110.563320 -124.948033 -121.455465
1      RU1  112  120  104  -17.513545  -48.205310  -32.040780
2      RU1  106  115  115   34.402681    3.013596  -23.436698
3      RU1  134   94  108    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
4      RU1   99  115  122    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
5      RU1  134  113   89    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
6      RU1   91  128  117    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
7      RU1  105  115  116    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
8      RU1  113  121  102    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
9      RU1  101  125  111    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Comment: How would I then addin the other column results? 1 through 9

Comment: Do you think concat all dataframe together? - `print (pd.concat([df_Z0.sort_index(level=1),df_Z1.sort_index(level=1),df_Z2.sort_index(level=1)]))`

Comment: Sorry, I think I dont understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: close, however, now I have additional rows with 0.0 values. I need them put together as shown in the example.

Comment: So do you need all rows with `0` ?

Comment: No, no 0.0 values. Sorry if wasn't clear. Take a look at the last picture.

Comment: Hi jezrael, this works. Would it be possible to write a for loop like this;for a in ['Z']:
    for num in list(range(0,2)):
        df['_{}{}'.format(a, num)] = (df['bin_{}_{}'.format(a,num)]).groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).set_index('size', append=True)

Comment: Problem is output is not new column of `df`, but DataFrame. So you need distionary of dataframes like `dfs = {}
for a in ['Z']: 
    for num in list(range(0,2)): 
        dfs['_{}{}'.format(a, num)] = df['bin_{}_{}'.format(a,num)].groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).set_index('size', append=True)` and then select dataframe by `print (dfs['_Z0'])`

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly the result I need. J/size need to unstack I guess and also, I'm not getting the bins_Z as shown in my example above.

Comment: I find bug - need `range(3)` like `dfs = {}
for a in ['Z']: 
    for num in range(3): 
        dfs['_{}{}'.format(a, num)] = df['bin_{}_{}'.format(a,num)].groupby([df.bins_Z, df.S, df.J]).agg(['sum','size']).set_index('size', append=True)` and then `print (dfs['_Z0'].add(dfs['_Z1']).add(dfs['_Z2']).reset_index(level=3).unstack().sort_index(level='S'))
`